# What does Rekognition count as one metadata?

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, amazon-rekognition

I want to create a collection of faces from 1500 face images and then [compare](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html) this collection with one reference face image. The final goal is to find which face from the collection is the most similar one to the reference face image.

So I want to retrieve one number for similarity for each pair of images (reference image and one face from the collection) each time.

So does this amount to 1500faces x 1similarity_metadata = 1500metadata or the similarity attribute is counted as one metadata for any number of face images?

In other words, does my request amount to 1500 metadata or 1 metadata for the 1500 faces?

I am using the free version and AWS specifies that:

> As part of the AWS Free Tier, you can get started with Amazon
>   Rekognition Image for free. Upon sign-up, new Amazon Rekognition
>   customers can analyze 5,000 images per month and store up to 1,000
>   face metadata each month, for the first 12 month.

So I am asking this because I do not want to exceed the limit of 1000 face metadata each month.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how this works if you want to find out which of 1500 faces is the closest to your test face:

- create a Rekognition Faces collection using [CreateCollection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_CreateCollection.html)
- store faces in the collection by indexing the faces in the 1500 images using [IndexFaces](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/collections-index-faces.html)
- search the face collection for your test face using [SearchFacesByImage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/API_SearchFacesByImage.html) which returns an array of faces that match, ordered by similarity score with the highest similarity first

The free tier allows you to store up to 1,000 face metadata each month. When you call IndexFaces for one image, Rekognition finds faces in that image and stores one metadata per face in the Faces Collection. So if you call IndexFaces on 500 images and each image has 2 recognizable faces in it, then I would assume that amounts to 1000 metadata.

However, I suspect that the way billing works is as follows: AWS calculates how many 'face-days' you consume in a given month. Free tier allows you 1000x30 face-days (assuming 30 days in month). So, you could store 1000 faces for 30 days, or you could equally store 2000 faces for 15 days. Both amount to the same number of face-days and would (I think) fit into free tier. I am making assumptions here (based on what AWS does for other services). Caveat emptor.

By the way, pricing is $0.01 (1 cent) per 1000 metadata per month beyond the free tier so any time that you spend designing a solution to stay within the free tier limits will probably cost you many orders of magnitude more than you would spend simply storing the metadata.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I suppose that similarity is a metadatum because it is a datum about the images which are data. So my question is if what I will do implies that I will have to download and store 1500 metadata or not? (See also my edited post at the end)

Comment: So from your answer I can infer that I will exceed the limit since I use 1500 images with one face at least in each image. Do you have any idea how to do what I want without exceeding this limit?

Comment: I suspect that the way this works is as follows: AWS calculates how many 'face-days' you consume in a given month. Your free tier allows you 1000x30 face-days (assuming 30 days in month). So, you could store 1000 faces for 30 days, or you could equally store 2000 faces for 15 days. Both amount to the same number of face-days and would (I think) fit into free tier. But, AWS does not spell out its formula to this level, so I am making assumptions here (based on what they do for other services). Caveat emptor.

Comment: Ok, I got your point. Yes, AWS is not very clear about it. Also I sent them an email and they said that I need the premium subscription to get a detailed response to it. However, I have the feeling that they did not understand my question otherwise I do not get why they cannot respond to this simple question. Anyways...!?!